# Java bytecode dynamic analysis

Tags: java, jar

I've been trying to patch a certain functionality of a jar file, that's essentially a GUI app. I've tried numerous java agents -as it seems to be the only viable option for java- for such a task, however quite a few limitations arose. Namely:

- Previously loaded classes don't fire up again during logging (causes plot holes).
- Specific method calls are often omitted.
- Real time decompilation is unheard of when it comes this approach, even though it's generally feasible.

I was wondering if there's a better approach -or an alternative that addresses those 'issues'- to go about dynamically analyse java executables, and not just instrumentation; as it seems to be geared more towards debugging during development rather than reverse engineering.

Comment: So your question is a bout temporarily modifying a Java program? Because for a permanent modification it would be easier to directly modify the class files. For temporary modification https://frida.re should be suitable. Hooking and modifying method arguments and return values should be easier with Frida than using an JavaAgent.

Comment: @Robert  `your question is a bout temporarily modifying a Java program?` It's more about understanding the obfuscated code, by interacting with certain functionalities at the app itself then simultaneously seeing which specific portions are getting called, and selectively inspect them (that's why i was asking for concurrent deobfuscation to omit this separate inspection stage).
`should be easier with Frida than using an JavaAgent.` Aw. I thought it was only confined to Android.

Comment: Since Frida 12.10 there is also support for HotSpot JVM (non-Android) https://frida.re/news/2020/06/29/frida-12-10-released/

Comment: Thanks. Will look into frida as of now, as I've never dealt with it before.